# Storing chars into a string with a for loop?

Tags: c, string, char

I have this function, bits_show, which prints to stdout a 2-3 bit long code.

```
void bits_show(bits *a)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < a->next; i++)
    putchar(a->bits[i]);
}
```

where bits:

```
struct bits {
  int capacity;
  int next;
  char *bits;
};
```

I am trying to write a function, char* bits_char(bits *a) that captures these characters and collects them into a single char* file.

This is what I have so far, but it keeps spitting errors:

```
char* bits_char(bits *a)
{
  char* str = (char*) malloc( sizeof(a->next * char));
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<a->next; i++){
    str[i] = (a->bits[i]);
  }
  return str;
}
```

"bits.c: In function ‘bits_char’:

bits.c:33: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

bits.c:37: warning: function returns address of local variable"

Comment: I added a malloc, but I am still getting an error saying "expected expression before ‘char’" on the line of the malloc.

Comment: update the code and show the malloc

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
sizeof(a->next * char)
```

I presume you meant to write:

```
a->next * sizeof(char)
```

But since `sizeof(char)` equals 1 by definition you would simply omit that.

But even that is wrong since you need to allow space for the null terminator which your code does not currently write. The allocation needs to be:

```
malloc(a->next+1)
```

And add the null-terminator like this:

```
str[a->next] = 0;
```

All in all, the finished product is as so:

```
char* bits_char(bits *a)
{
  char* str = malloc(a->next+1);
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<a->next; i++){
    str[i] = (a->bits[i]);
  }
  str[a->next] = 0;
  return str;
}
```

I removed the cast of the return value of `malloc` which is not needed in C.

And you should also ensure that you check the return value of `malloc` for a failed allocation. It will return the null pointer if it fails. I've not shown how to do that because I don't know your error handling policy.

Comment: Null check after malloc is missing. +1

Comment: @BillyONeal Thanks, I had a nagging feeling I'd forgotten something!!